# Is there a function in Haskell that can replicate Chars and Strings

Tags: string, haskell, char, concatenation, replication

For example say I had 'A' I could call the function like so:

```
replicate 'A' 5 ~> "AAAAA"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, exact same name but the arguments are switched.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate

If you go to hoogle you can search functions by type signature and name.

http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Int+-%3E+String

See that `replicate` was the 3rd result.

Answer (score 2):

It's replicate in the prelude.

```
replicate 5 'A'
```

returns:
"AAAAA"